# pfSense + Squid, Windows 2008 DHCP

Tags: windows-server-2008, dhcp, squid, pfsense

I recently installed pfSense and Squid3-dev on a spare machine. It is now connected to the network and Internet is working alright.

The problem is that I can't get my users to go through Squid proxy even though I have set it up with LDAP authentication with explicit (non-transparent proxy).

The reason seems to be that my windows 2008 domain controller which is also the dhcp server assigns the gateway to all clients. The gateway ip is that of my pfsense system. IS this why squid is bypassed? If so, how can i stop the dhcp server from providing gateway? I checked the configuration snap-in and there is no entry for router.

I hope the question makes sense. I am really at loss..I think I am going grossly wrong somewhere.